# How to remove the junk characters from string in aes128 decryption

Tags: iphone, objective-c, aes, encryption

The problem is encryption in server side they are using ISO10126d2Padding and decryption is happening but after decryption it is showing some junk values anyone please help remove that :

**ACTUAL RESULT = india ismy**
***DECRYPTED VALUE = India ismyg~²t**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will not say that this is the best way to remove unwanted characters from NSString but i did this ... and it is great.

```
NSString * str = @"your string";
NSMutableString * newString;
int j = [str length];
for (int i=0; i<j; i++) {       
    if (([str characterAtIndex:i] >=65 && [str characterAtIndex:i] <=90) || ([str characterAtIndex:i] >=97 && [str characterAtIndex:i] <=122) ||[str characterAtIndex:i] == 32 ) {
        [newString appendFormat:@"%c",[str characterAtIndex:i]];
    }               
}

//([str characterAtIndex:i] >=65 && [str characterAtIndex:i] <=90) this is ASCII limit for A-Z
//([str characterAtIndex:i] >=97 && [str characterAtIndex:i] <=122) this is ASCII limit for a-z
//and [str characterAtIndex:i] == 32 is for space.
```

Now, print new string

```
NSLog(@"%@",newString);
```

let me know if it is woking for you!

Thank You!

Comment: resolved the issue !!!! thank u Vakul

Comment: Modded it down because this is not how ISO10126d2Padding works, I'm glad it worked for this specific use case, but this should not be used generally.

Comment: @owlstead -  be cool .... look at my first two lines... I have already told this... I'm wonder you gave me down vote before read the answer correctly......